# nested for loop

Tags: python, loops, nested

Just learning Python and trying to do a nested for loop.  What I'd like to do in the end is place a bunch of email addresses in a file and have this script find the info, like the sending IP of mail ID. For now i'm testing it on my /var/log/auth.log file

Here is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# this section puts emails from file(SpamEmail) in to a array(array)
in_file = open("testFile", "r")
array = in_file.readlines()
in_file.close()

# this section opens and reads the target file, in this case 'auth.log'
log = open("/var/log/auth.log", "r")
auth = log.readlines()

for email in array:
    print "Searching for " +email,
    for line in auth:
         if line.find(email) > -1:
                about = line.split()
                print about[0],
    print
```

Inside 'testfile' I have the word 'disconnect' cause I know it's in the auth.log file. It just doesn't find the word 'disconnect'.  In the line of "if line.find(email) > -1:" i can replace email and put "disconnect" the scripts finds it fine.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.
Gary

Comment: What's the output you get?  Do you get "Searching for disconnect"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but an obvious problem with the above is that `readlines()` returns a list of lines, each of which (except potentially the last) will have a `\n` line terminator. So `email` will have a newline at the end of it, so won't be found in `line` unless it's right at the end.

So perhaps something like:

```
with open('testFile', 'r') as f:
    emails= f.read().split('\n')
with open('/var/log/auth.log', 'r') as f:
    lines= f.read().split('\n')

for email in emails:
    for linei, line in enumerate(lines):
        if email in line:
            print 'Line %d, found:' % linei
            print line
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I needed to add `from __future__ import with_statement`.